# Gibbs sampler, how to generate samples based on odds?

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

I am reading a paper that contains a Gibbs sampler for a regression model with parameters $\beta$ and design matrix $X$. One of the steps in the Gibbs sampler requires simulating from a binary random variable $Z$, and the authors only say

> Generate $Z$ based on
> $$
> \frac{P(Z=1 \mid \beta, X)}{P(Z=0 \mid \beta, X)} = \psi(\beta,X),
> $$

where $\beta$ and $X$ are known in this step of the Gibbs sampler, and $\psi$ is a known function.

Do they mean that somehow I need to transform the odds $\frac{p}{1-p} = \frac{P(Z=1 \mid \beta, X)}{P(Z=0 \mid \beta, X)}$ to be able to simulate from $Z$?

That is, do I need to generate $Z$ with probability $p = \frac{\psi(\beta,X)}{1+\psi(\beta,X)}$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.